# Undefined variable в view MVC

Tags: php, mvc, view, controller

Есть такая проблема переменная объявленная в контроллере не работает в шаблоне.Подскажите проблему пожалуйста. Вот код .Заранее спасибо.

**Controller.php**

```
class ExampleController{

  public function indexAction(){

         require_once("layout/contact.php");
  }

  private function checkAction($data){

         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         $data = strip_tags($data);
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripsclashes($data);
         return $data;
  }

  public function someAction(){

   $name = "";
   $age ="";
   $city = "";
   $country = "";

   if(isset($_POST["button"])){

            $name = $this->checkAction($_POST["name"]);
            $age = $this->checkAction($_POST["age"]);
            $city = $this->checkAction($_POST["city"]);
            $country = $this->checkAction($_POST["country"]);

   }

   require_once("layout/contact.php");

   }
```

**View**

*layout/contact.php*

```
<form action="#" class="contact-form" method="POST">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter  Name" id="cont">
    <?php print($name); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age" id="cont">
    <?php print($age); ?>                           
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter City" id="cont">
    <?php print($city); ?>                              
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Enter Country" id="cont">
<?php print($city); ?>
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">
   <button type="submit" name="button" id="mss-btn">Send Message</button>
</div>
</form>



Output:
 Undefined variable 
 $name;
 $age;
 $city;
 $country;
```

Comment: Что это за `Output:`? Как вы вообще его выводите?

Comment: Это для простого понимания.Настоящий пример выглядит так  `Notice: Undefined variable: name in`

Comment: А как вызываете саму функцию `someAction()`?  Каким образом у вас отправка происходит? ajax?

Comment: И у вас в этой строке - `$data = stripsclashes($data)` ошибка, есть функция `stripslashes()`, у вас же опечатка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы делаете *require_once("layout/contact.php")*, 
ваш шаблон ничего не может знать о переменных которые объявлены в методе другого класса, он находится в другой области видимости.

Самый простой и самый плохой путь: установить значения в глобальную переменную, например в GET, Но так делать не стоит.

Создайте еще один файл ViewData

```
 class ViewData {
   protected static  $data = [];

   public static function getData() {
     return self::$data;
   }

   public static function setData($key, $value) {
      self::$data[$key] = $value;
   }
}

ViewData::setData('foo', 'bar');

ViewData::getData('foo', 'bar');
```

подключите его в контроллере и создайте через new ViewData()

```
 require_once("ViewData.php");
```

Затем в контроллере  устанавливайте переменные  ::setData($key, $value)
Подключите этот же файл в свой шаблон и доставайте из него установленные значения
через  ::getData($key, $value)